# How do I loop across both rows and columns of a range in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, range

I'm trying to create a Gantt chart type display using only cell values. Formulas will not work due to formatting so I need to have VBA run instead.

I want to loop across the both the columns and rows of a single named range. However, I don't think the VBA format is correct as this errors out "438: Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
Dim d As Integer
Dim e As Integer
For d = 1 To **Range("PRcal").Cols.Count**
    For e = 1 To **Range("PRcal").Rows.Count**
        If [Range("PRcal").Cells.(e, d).Value = Range("PRcal").Cells(1, d).Value] Then
            Cells(e, d).Value = Cells(e, 1)
        End If
    Next e
Next d
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: One thing is you need to use `Columns` instead of `Cols`

Answer (score 3):

- Ranges don't have a `Cols` property - they do have a `Columns` property
- you have an extra dot in your `if` in `Cells.(e,d)`
- you can't use square brackets in your `if`

This should work fine:

```
Dim d As Integer
Dim e As Integer
For d = 1 To Range("PRcal").Columns.Count
    For e = 1 To Range("PRcal").Rows.Count
        If Range("PRcal").Cells(e, d).Value = Range("PRcal").Cells(1, d).Value Then
            Cells(e, d).Value = Cells(e, 1)
        End If
    Next e
Next d
```

Comment: Hooray! Columns/Rows property works great! The extra dot was just typo. Thank you!